# Why can I use `operator<<` on temporary std::ofstream objects?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, temporary-objects

According to the C++ standard you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference. Since the stream output operator is defined as

```cpp
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>

std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```

I would expect it to not be callable on temporary stream objects. However, I tried the following and got unexpected results

```cpp
#include <fstream>

std::ostream& print(std::ostream &stream) {
    stream << "test\n";
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    std::fstream("") << "test\n";
    // print(std::fstream("")); // Doesn't compile, as expected
}
```

This compiles on GCC trunk, Clang trunk and MSVC 19. I even tried `-pedantic-errors` on the first two. While technically possible that all three are wrong, it is likely that I am misunderstanding something.

Can somebody find a definitive answer in the standard on whether this is legal C++ or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard mandates the following function template existing (C++17 n4659 30.7.5.5 [ostream.rvalue]):

```
template <class charT, class traits, class T>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os, const T& x);
```

With effects specified as `os << x`.

Note that the same exists for extraction (`>>`) as well.

Comment: Interesting. I was mislead by [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) into assuming there was no r-value reference version. In fact, I even verified that the l-value version I posted was called in the assembly of gcc and clang. Obviously it was because of inlining but it reinforced my misunderstanding.

Comment: @patatahooligan To be fair, there indeed is no rvalue version specific for `std::basic_string`, so the page is correct. This generic template covers all types, though.

Answer (score 9):

There is overload which takes stream by Rvalue reference:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class T >
basic_ostream< CharT, Traits >& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&& os,
                                        const T& value );
```

temp is passed as `os`. From [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).